# When exactly a Spark task can be serialized?

Tags: scala, serialization, closures, apache-spark

I read some related questions about this topic, but still cannot understand the following. I have this simple Spark application which reads some JSON records from a file:

```
object Main {

  // implicit val formats = DefaultFormats // OK: here it works

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Spark Test App")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val input = sc.textFile("/home/alex/data/person.json")

    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats // Exception: Task not serializable

    val persons = input.flatMap { line ⇒
      // implicit val formats = DefaultFormats // OK: here it also works
      try {
        val json = parse(line)
        Some(json.extract[Person])
      } catch {
        case e: Exception ⇒ None
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I suppose the implicit `formats` is not serializable since it includes some `ThreadLocal` for the date format. But, why it works when placed as a member of the `object Main` or inside the closure of `flatMap`, and not as a common `val` inside the `main` function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If the `formats` is inside the `flatMap`, it's only created as part of executing the mapping function. So the mapper can be serialized and sent to the cluster, since it doesn't contain a `formats` yet. The flipside is that this will create `formats` anew every time the mapper runs (i.e. once for every row) - you might prefer to use `mapPartitions` rather than `flatMap` so that you can have the value created once for each partition.

If `formats` is outside the `flatMap` then it's created once on the master machine, and you're attempting to serialize it and send it to the cluster.

I don't understand why `formats` as a field of `Main` would work. Maybe `object`s are magically pseudo-serializable because they're singletons (i.e. their fields aren't actually serialized, rather the fact that this is a reference to the single static `Main` instance is serialized)? That's just a guess though.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to answer your question I think is in three short answers:

1) **Why it works when placed as a member of the object Main?**, the question here is that code works because it's inside an Object, not necessary the Main Object. And now: Why? because Spark serializes your whole object and send it to each of the executors, moreover an Object in Scala is generated like a JAVA Static class and the initial values of static fields in a Java class are stored in the jar and workers can use it directly. This is not the same if you use a class instead an Object.

2) **The second question is: why it works if it's inside a flatmap?**.
When you run transformations on a RDD (filter, flatMap ... etc), your transformation code  is: serialized on the driver node, send to worker, once there it will be deserialized and executed. As you can see exactly the same as in 1) the code will be serialized "automatycally".

And finally the 3) question: **Why this is not working as a common val inside the main function?** this is because the val is not serialized "automatically", but you can test it like this: `val yourVal = new yourVal with Serializable`